# Improving the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, compounds

"You must work hard or you will not succeed in life"

How can I convert the above into simple sentence?

Comment: Why is the sentence you've given not simple enough? When does a sentence qualify as simple in your opinion?

Comment: Here is a simpler sentence: "Hard work is the key to success." Also it contains more 'carrot' than 'stick'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can kind of see what you are saying since the sentence is compound, you could say "Success comes from hard work, none of it comes from laziness."